# LSTM (long short memory) on Penn Tree Bank data

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

The PennTree Bank data seems difficult to understand. Below are two links 
https://github.com/townie/PTB-dataset-from-Tomas-Mikolov-s-webpage/tree/master/data
https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/recurrent

My concern is as follows. The reader gives me around a million occurrences of 10000 words. I have written code to convert this data set into one-hot encoding. Thus, I have a million vectors of 10000 dimensions, each vector having a 1 at a single location. Now, I want to train a LSTM (long short term memory) model on this for prediction.

For simplicity let us assume that there are 30 (and not a million occurences) occurences, and the sequence length is equal to 10 for the LSTM (the number of timesteps that it unrolls). Let us denote these occurences by

```
X1,X2,....,X10,X11,...,X20,X21,...X30
```

Now, my concern is that should I use 3 data samples for training

X1,..X10 and X11,..,X20, and X21,..X30

or should I use 20 data samples for training
X1,..X10 and X2,...,X11, and X3,..,X12, so on until X21,..,X30

In case I go with the latter, then am I not breaking the i.i.d. assumption of training data sequence generations?

Comment: You are using this for prediction, right? How do you define your targets? In the past when I do prediction on time series, my targets are my input time series shifted one step forward so at each training step I am trying to predict the next thing the network will see. I think I usually then train on *every* series of `n` samples for `n` unrollings, with the `n+1`th sample being the target, and move forward one sample per training operation. So I guess I'd lean toward the latter, but I'm not positive it's best.

Comment: @Engineero , yes I am using it for predictions. I use the same method as yours for deciding the target sequence. The codes on github are bit cryptic with regards to what is the current norm.